# Unable to figure out the output of the code for PHP

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP, just started learning and I have written the below code:

The output of the above code is: Doesnt exist1Doesnt exist

I understand that this happened because of foreach loop, how do I avoid this without using for loop?

Also, my desired output is only the key, i.e: 1, in this case.

TIA

Raksha

```
<?php
       $programmingLanguages = ['php','java','giga'];
         foreach ($programmingLanguages as $key => $language){
         if($language=='java'){
            echo $key;
        }
        else
            echo 'Doesnt exist';
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you simply looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php ?

Answer (score 1):

the code is checking whether each element in the array is equal to the string "java" since the first element is not equal to java the if condition fails

```
<?php
   $programmingLanguages = ['php', 'java', 'giga'];
   $found = false;
   for($i = 0; $i < count($programmingLanguages); $i++){
      if($programmingLanguages[$i] == 'java'){
         echo $i;
         $found = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if(!$found){
      echo 'Doesnt exist';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Wow, this makes so much sense, thank you , Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

a simpler method will be to use array_search() function. The array_search() function search an array for a value and returns the key.

here is the example:

```
<?php
       $programmingLanguages = ['php','giga','java'];

      $key = array_search('java',$programmingLanguages) ;

      echo $key;
?>
```

for more info here is the link: [array_search refrence](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp)

Comment: Thnak you Anant for this solution.